# The difference between "anyway" and "any way"

Tags: differences, orthography, spacing

When to use *anyway* and when to use *any way*?

> - Anyway I can do it.
> - Any way I can do it.

Are these the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Anyway* is an example of a [discourse marker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_marker), one of whose functions is "*to indicate what speakers think about what they are saying or what others have said*". (Swan, *Practical English Usage*, p138). Swan groups *anyway* together with *anyhow, at any rate*, and *in any case*, and describes their function as follows:

> These four expressions are used (mostly informally) to mean '*What was
>   said before doesn't matter - the main point is as follows'*.  Example: 
>   - *I'm not sure  what time I'll arrive, maybe seven or eight. Anyway, I'll certainly be
>   there before eight thirty.*

Swan goes on to point out the difference between *anyway* and *in any way*:

> Note that *anyway* is not the same as *in any way*, which means *by any
>   method*. Example: *Can I help you in any way?*

By these principles the discourse marker *anyway* in *Anyway I can do it!* implies some prior statement. For example: *I'm not sure if I'll have time on Friday or Saturday. Anyway I can do it.*

The second statement *Any way I can do it* has the noun *way* preceded by the determiner *any*, and implies some continuation. For example. *Any way I can do it I will*. Or more likely: *I will do it in any way I can*.

Comment: '_Be that as it may_ (, . . .)' is perhaps the most transparent member of this group Swan gives four examples of; it is less commonly used*, probably because of lack of succinctness. There is good reason to analyse the grammar of discourse markers (in fact, all pragmatic markers) separately from that of the matrix sentence. Whether we should call them all 'pragmatic markers', no matter how many words they consist of, ie treat them principally as MW units rather than break them down into words with individual classes, is moot.

Comment: *A very Christmassy Ngram for [decoration](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=be+that+as+it+may%2Canyway%2Cin+any+case%2Canyhow%2Cat+any+rate&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbe%20that%20as%20it%20may%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canyway%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20any%20case%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canyhow%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20any%20rate%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @Edwin. Yes, _Be that as it may_ fits with _anyway_ etc. in the same group of  markers that Swan categorizes as '_dismissal of previous discourse_'. This is just one of the 21 discourse marker categories he discusses. I didn't point it out in my answer but in fact the adjunct _anyway_ can have other somewhat different functions. For example: _Why are you asking me that anyway_?. An interesting topic!

Comment: Thanks – I was searching for the subsubclass! I love 'dismissal of previous discourse' (but I'm glad it's not just me coming up with these mouthfuls). You begin to have a bit of sympathy for the universal-adverbialist. Swan's classification is very helpful and comprehensive. The second usage you mention is an interaction-focusing marker as well as being dismissive of previous discourse content.

Comment: And then we have: _He told me not to buy him a present but I'm going to do it anyway_. And: _Do you need help? - No, but thanks anyway_. I guess these come under the broad category of _dismissal of previous discourse_; maybe they need their own subsubsubclasses!

Comment: I hate it when people come up with sensible reasons for schmadverbs. What about nuclear subclasses?

Comment: A simpler way to explain the difference is that "anyway" is typically a synonym for "regardless", while "any way" is not.